# AndroidAndroid: kivy sounds play on pc but dont run on android

Tags: python, android, kivy, buildozer

If I run my Code on pc it works normaly and sounds are playing. But on Android Nothing happendes when I click The Button. There is no error in the build file and I dont know what I should do. I already tried to change the file-types firts I used .mp3 then I used .wav and now I am using .ogg . But nothings seems to work. Please Help

main.py:

```
import kivy
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import *
from kivy.app import App
import random
kivy.require("1.9.0")



class BoxLayout1(BoxLayout):

    def ButtonChangeUp(self):
        sound1 = SoundLoader.load('BabaG.ogg')
        sound2 = SoundLoader.load("Ekes Bokes Seres Ekes.ogg")
        sound3 = SoundLoader.load("Logitech.ogg")
        sound4 = SoundLoader.load("GrandteftotoDini.ogg")
        sound5 = SoundLoader.load("Palastationfive.ogg")

        random1 = ["Rokie Rokie", "Lil Nas Nuss Nuss", "Lil Baby", "Chriano Rodado", "Fortineity"]
        self.ids.b2.text = random.choice(random1)
        if self.ids.b1.text == "BabaG":
            if sound1:
                sound1.play()
        if self.ids.b1.text == "Ekes Bokes Seres Ekes":
            if sound2:
                sound2.play()
        if self.ids.b1.text == "Plastation feiv":
            if sound5:
                sound5.play()
        if self.ids.b1.text == "Lotschitek":
            if sound3:
                sound3.play()
        if self.ids.b1.text == "Grand teft oto Dini":
            if sound4:
                sound4.play()

    def ButtonChangeUp2(self):
        sound1 = SoundLoader.load("RockieRockie.ogg")
        sound2 = SoundLoader.load("LilNassNUSSNUSS.ogg")
        sound3 = SoundLoader.load("lilBaby.ogg")
        sound4 = SoundLoader.load("ChrianoRodao.ogg")
        sound5 = SoundLoader.load('Fortineity.ogg')

        random2 = ["BabaG", "Ekes Bokes Seres Ekes", "Lotschitek", "Grand teft oto Dini", "Plastation feiv"]
        self.ids.b1.text = random.choice(random2)

        if self.ids.b2.text == "Fortineity":
            if sound5:
                sound5.play()
        if self.ids.b2.text == "Rokie Rokie":
            if sound1:
                sound1.play()
        if self.ids.b2.text == "Lil Nas Nuss Nuss":
            if sound2:
                sound2.play()
        if self.ids.b2.text == "Lil Baby":
            if sound3:
                sound3.play()
        if self.ids.b2.text == "Chriano Rodado":
            if sound4:
                sound4.play()


class pycharm(App):
    def build(self):
        return BoxLayout1()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pycharm().run()
```

pycharm.kv:

```
BoxLayout1:

<BoxLayout1>:

    orientation: "vertical"
    spacing: "10dp"
    padding: [dp(0),dp(150),dp(0),dp(150)]

    Image:
        source:"Download (3).jpg"
        width: 1000
        height: 1000
        allow_stretch: False

    Button:
        id: b1
        text: "BabaG"
        size_hint: .5, None
        pos_hint: {"x": .25}
        height: "40dp"
        on_release: root.ButtonChangeUp()
    Label:
        text: "ela"

    Button:
        id: b2
        text: "Fortineity"
        size_hint: .5, None
        pos_hint: {"x": .25}
        height: "40dp"
        on_release: root.ButtonChangeUp2()
```

buildozer.spec :

```
package.name = FortineityelaBabaG

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.test

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy,ffpyplayer, python-for-android

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (list) Garden requirements
#garden_requirements =

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/Image1.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, sensorLandscape, portrait or all)
orientation = portrait

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 1.9.1

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0

# (string) Presplash background color (for new android toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
#android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF

# (list) Permissions
#android.permissions = INTERNET

# (int) Target Android API, should be as high as possible.
#android.api = 27

# (int) Minimum API your APK will support.
#android.minapi = 21

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 20

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 19b

# (int) Android NDK API to use. This is the minimum API your app will support, it should usually match android.minapi.
#android.ndk_api = 21

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ant_path =

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
# android.skip_update = False

# (bool) If True, then automatically accept SDK license
# agreements. This is intended for automation only. If set to False,
# the default, you will be shown the license when first running
# buildozer.
# android.accept_sdk_license = False

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (str) Android app theme, default is ok for Kivy-based app
# android.apptheme = "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"

# (list) Pattern to whitelist for the whole project
#android.whitelist =

# (str) Path to a custom whitelist file
#android.whitelist_src =

# (str) Path to a custom blacklist file
#android.blacklist_src =

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (list) Android AAR archives to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.add_aars =

# (list) Gradle dependencies to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.gradle_dependencies =

# (list) add java compile options
# this can for example be necessary when importing certain java libraries using the 'android.gradle_dependencies' option
# see https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support for further information
# android.add_compile_options = "sourceCompatibility = 1.8", "targetCompatibility = 1.8"

# (list) Gradle repositories to add {can be necessary for some android.gradle_dependencies}
# please enclose in double quotes 
# e.g. android.gradle_repositories = "maven { url 'https://kotlin.bintray.com/ktor' }"
#android.add_gradle_repositories =

# (list) packaging options to add 
# see https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html
# can be necessary to solve conflicts in gradle_dependencies
# please enclose in double quotes 
# e.g. android.add_packaging_options = "exclude 'META-INF/common.kotlin_module'", "exclude 'META-INF/*.kotlin_module'"
#android.add_gradle_repositories =

# (list) Java classes to add as activities to the manifest.
#android.add_activities = com.example.ExampleActivity

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (str) launchMode to set for the main activity
#android.manifest.launch_mode = standard

# (list) Android additional libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_arm64_v8a = libs/android-v8/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

# (list) Android shared libraries which will be added to AndroidManifest.xml using <uses-library> tag
#android.uses_library =

# (str) Android logcat filters to use
#android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
#android.copy_libs = 1

# (str) The Android arch to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64
android.arch = armeabi-v7a

# (int) overrides automatic versionCode computation (used in build.gradle)
# this is not the same as app version and should only be edited if you know what you're doing
# android.numeric_version = 1

#
# Python for android (p4a) specific
#

# (str) python-for-android fork to use, defaults to upstream (kivy)
#p4a.fork = kivy

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to master
#p4a.branch = master

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#p4a.source_dir =

# (str) The directory in which python-for-android should look for your own build recipes (if any)
#p4a.local_recipes =

# (str) Filename to the hook for p4a
#p4a.hook =

# (str) Bootstrap to use for android builds
# p4a.bootstrap = sdl2

# (int) port number to specify an explicit --port= p4a argument (eg for bootstrap flask)
#p4a.port =
```

Comment: Try adding `ogg` to `source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas`.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked. I tried so long but didnt find out. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It finally workked I changed this  `source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas` to this  `source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas`